# WCF Array Serialization - REST

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

I have a REST web service that returns a structure containing an array of more structures. This return structure looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response {
  private ResponseRecord[] m_Record;

  [DataMember]
  public int TotalRecords { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public ResponseRecord[] Record {
    get { return m_Record; }
    set { m_Record = value; }
  }
}
```

The ResponseRecord class is like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="Record")]
public class ResponseRecord {
  [DataMember(Order = 0)]
  public string RecordID { get; set; }
/* Many more objects */
}
```

My web service returns XML like this:

```
<Response>
  <TotalRecords>1</TotalRecords>
  <Record>
    <ResponseRecord>
      <RecordID>1</RecordID>
      ... Many more objects ...
    </ResponseRecord>
  </Record>
</Response>
```

What I would like to do is get rid of that "ResponseRecord" hierarchal level, as it adds no new information. This web service also runs for SOAP and XML, and  the (Name="Record") attribute did the trick. Not so for REST for some reason, though. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my array was set up incorrectly:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response {
  private ResponseRecord[] m_Record;

  [DataMember]
  public int TotalRecords { get; set; }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Record")]   // <-- HERE
  public ResponseRecord[] Record {
    get { return m_Record; }
    set { m_Record = value; }
  }
}
```

This removed the ResponseRecord level, which is what I wanted gone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you change `Record` property to `Records` as records is really what it is.

Also, if you remove `ResponseRecord`, there won't be anything to group the properties of each `ResponseRecord` instance together. So it is not possible.

Comment: I think I meant to say that I wanted to get rid of the <Record> level. Is this possible?